# React Material UI: Why is the primary color different to the one in the docs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I started using Material UI framework for some project in React. There is one thing i can't figure out: The primary color, which appears all over the documentation, seems to be #2196f3, but in my project it's, for some reason, #303f9f (something between blue and purple).

I'm using standard examples, without any themes or global CSS that might interfere. For instance, this:

```
<Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" >
   Register event
</Button>
```

The result is:

[image]

Am i missing something in the documentation? Why could the color be so different?

Comment: I'm sure the documentation has a different theme than the default one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the documentation for the default theme:

https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/

Within that page you can find the following:

> Please take note that the documentation site is using a custom theme.
>   As a result, the demos you see here might disagree with the values
>   above.

To learn more about the color system see https://material.io/design/color/#

Answer (score 2):

The palette of the [default theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/) is different from the [doc site](https://material-ui.com/style/color/#color-tool).

[image]